# Motherboard for work computer with 2-Ethernet ports

Tags: motherboard, ethernet

My work computer is very slow, and so I am looking to upgrade some of the parts. I have the intel i5-4440 that I'm going to put in it, but this CPU is not compatible with my current motherboard.

Here's the slightly esoteric requirement: I work with programming [EtherCAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherCAT) boards over an Ethernet port, and I also like to use Ethernet for my internet connection. Unfortunately, my current motherboard only has one Ethernet port, and no wifi card. This means I will frequently switch out my Ethernet cord from the router to the board I'm working on, and it's very annoying to have to pick between an internet connection and talking to the board I'm working on. (I suppose a better solution would be to buy a wifi card, but I'd like to keep the Ethernet connection if I can)

## Requirements

- Compatible with the i5 4440 CPU, DDR3 RAM and the GTX 610 GPU.
- At least 4 USB ports.
- Micro ATX
- Relatively cheap. I'm thinking around 70 USD.

## Preferences

- USB 3.0 would be awesome, but I could settle for 2.0 if I had to.

I don't have any strong brand or appearance preferences.

Comment: Dual Ethernet is only a common feature on server and high-end gaming boards; you'll have a hard time finding it on a board in your price range.  Do you really need both ports on the board itself, or is a dedicated card for one of the ports acceptable?

Comment: You might be able to go with a single port and add a ethernet adaptor? They're reasonably cheap, and there's even a few options that would go into mini pci-e ports typically used for wifi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MSI H81M-P33 LGA 1150 Intel H81 SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 Micro ATX Intel Motherboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813130731)

Here's what you get with a $45.99 price tag:
-6 USB ports (4x2.0, 2x3.0)
-Compatible with Core i7 / i5 / i3 / Pentium / Celeron (LGA1150)
-DDR3 1600/ 1333/ 1066 RAM
-MicroATX
-One Ethernet port (you won't find a motherboard with two at less than $250)

It comes with a standard PCIx connector, which should fit most common Graphics cards. Also, you did not specify the socket for the i5 you have, but [according to Intel](http://ark.intel.com/products/75038/Intel-Core-i5-4440-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_30-GHz) it uses the LGA1150 connector, which this board comes with.

As for your dual network requirements, might I suggest this nifty [150Mbs USB WiFi adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MTTJOY) or this [USB 2.0 to Ethernet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ET4KHJ2) adapter from Amazon. They are very compatible, and just about as good as you'll get under $10. For another $7, you can get a [USB 3.0 to Ethernet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BBD7NFU) adapter for a much faster 1000Mbs over the 100Mbs of the USB 2.0 adapter.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative would be to use an internal Ethernet add-on card. It's a lot better than the USB solution usually...

One (very cheap) example:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA5M11TB9358

Advantages to other solutions:

- works with most motherboards
- better speed than USB 2.0 options
- doesn't take up any USB 3.0 ports
- cheaper than many alternatives

It has better bandwidth and reliability than the USB options suggested earlier, and it can be cheaply added to ANY motherboard someone else suggests as the solution, which allows total overall cost to be much lower (given that 2x ethernet port motherboards are indeed generally expensive). With an adapter like this, almost any motherboard that supports his chosen CPU will work just fine for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

**First solution - perfect match but expensive.**

Asus prepared solution which is perfect for your requirements but it's really expensive and it's over your budget. It's [ASUS CS-B](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/CSB/specifications/):

It meets your requirements:

Dual LAN:

- Intel® I217LM
- Realtek® 8111G

USB Ports

- 2 x USB 3.0
- 4 x USB 2.0

It's mATX.

But:

**Cost: $200 (Amazon US)**

---

**Second solution - better and cheaper**

You should just use [@john kieran solution](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2067/1366).